# How to add href attribute in <area> tag with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, area

How to add `href` attribute in `<area>` tag with jquery ?

```
<area alt="Drenthe" title="Drenthe" shape="poly" coords="141,44,145,38,154,43,159,43,168,54,171,57,173,68,174,77,172,77,169,77,172,77,170,79,168,77,166,77,154,77,151,77,147,79,139,75,135,73,136,68,136,62,139,59,144,59,146,57,146,53,144,51,142,48,142,44,140,39,144,39" filter="/vakantiehuizen/nederland/drenthe">
```

Comment: give it an id then do $('#id').href('http://yourlink')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('your-area-selecor').attr('href', 'value')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('area[title="Drenthe"]').attr('href','http://example.com');
```